# Is there any way to map between Standard Profile Name to its matching metadata file name?

Tags: metadata-api, profile, metadata

Is there any way to map between Standard Profile Name to its matching metadata file name ?

I.e. 'System Administrator' should be mapped to Admin etc.

Thanks.

Comment: It's also worth noting that these names are different for different languages. If you do a SOQL query for a profile named "System Administrator", it will fail if the user's language is set to something other than English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's at least three ways to map the names to their labels.

If you want just one value, you can use the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm):

```
SELECT Name, FullName FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'
```

Output:

```
Name                  FullName
System Administrator  Admin
```

The tooling API requires at most one result when returning the FullName field, so you'd have to query all profiles by Name alone, then filter for each profile by name or Id to get its FullName value.

---

To get all names and their corresponding values, you could use [listMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm), available in the Force.com Migration Toolkit, or you can write your own program to list and parse the results. In the Migration Toolkit, that looks like:

```
<sf:listMetadata metadataType="Profile" username="..." password="..." serverurl="..." />
```

---

The third option is to [readMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_readMetadata.htm), and then read the appropriate values from the XML. Each *.profile file will have its label inside. You could probably write up a quick Perl, Ruby, or NodeJS script if you wanted to just spit out the information in whatever format was easy for you.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox. Thanks for answering. 
I would like to perform the mapping for around 30+ profiles.

Third option is kind of problematic because I am restricted to maximum 10 results only .

First option is also problematic because I am restricted to 1 result only as I am retrieving the FullName field.

For the listMetadata option, can I match between the FileProperties getId() value and the Tooling Api query Id field  ?

Comment: @RonDaniel Yes, the Id in listMetadata is the same as used in the Tooling API, which is the same as the normal SOAP/REST APIs. I just checked to verify.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. you always help me a lot :)

Comment: @sfdcfox Should Tooling API query above be `SELECT Name, FullName FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'`

Comment: @AlanMorey Yes, it should have been. Thanks for letting me know, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took using jsForce was to make one call to [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm) to get
list of Profiles this includes their Id and FullName. Then a second query to the
[SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) to get list of Profiles, this includes their Id and Name.

Then simply merge the results where the Id's match and get both Name and FullName for each Profile.

Assuming `conn` is a valid [jsForce Connection](http://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Connection.html)

```js
const conn = ...;

const getProfilesMetadataApi = async () => {
    const profiles = await conn.metadata.list([{ type: 'Profile' }]);

    const profileById = p => [
        p.id, {
            id: p.id,
            fullName: p.fullName
        }
    ];

    return new Map(profiles.map(profileById));
};

const getProfilesSoapApi = async () => {
    const profiles = await conn.sobject('Profile')
        .select('Id, Name')
        .execute();

    const profileById = p => [
        p.Id, {
            id: p.Id,
            name: p.Name
        }
    ];

    return new Map(profiles.map(profileById));
};

const metaProfiles = await getProfilesMetadataApi();
const soapProfiles = await getProfilesSoapApi();

const profiles = new Map();

for (const [id, profile] of metaProfiles) {
    const mergedProfile = Object.assign(profile, soapProfiles.get(id));
    profiles.set(id, mergedProfile);
}
```

The `profiles` above is a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where the key is the Profile Id and value is a Profile data object with properties `{ id, name, fullName }`. It should be easy filter or create other maps from here.